# How can i read txt file and import it to sql database?

Tags: c#, readline

I have .txt files i want to read document and i want to store it to db.

Here is my txt file :

```
0 79 142
1 202 135
4 122 125
5 152 123
6 110 122
7 165 121
8 100 124
9 176 121
11 138 159
12 121 155
13 154 154
17 139 181
19 119 182
20 160 179
22 141 221
```

I want to read first integer which is 0 and then 79 , 142 . After then i will store 79 -> 0-X  and 142 -> 0-Y

Then 202 -> 1-X  and 135 -> 1-Y and this will continue like this..

I tried memoryStream but it reads as a string.. And i am not very good about C# also..

Here is what i tried ..

```
            int counter = 0;
            string line;


            System.IO.StreamReader file =
                new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\musa\Desktop\test\00002fa001d_931230_AP.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(line);
                counter++;
            }

            file.Close();

            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(counter));
```

So new question is how can i parse line ?

Comment: show us your attempt even if its not working!

Comment: do you need to do this with c#, or just store them into db with any easy way?

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis is there any way to store it in db easly ?

Comment: personally, what i would do is to open this as an excel delimitted file. This would fill columns A,B,C. Then in column D i would create the insert query and then run it in mysql. I don't know about others, but it would take to me about 2 minutes (a bit more if there are many columns)

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis very good approach thank you for information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a StreamReader?

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        Match match = Regex.Match(sr.ReadLine(), @"^(?<Index>\d+)\s(?<X>\d+)\s(?<Y>\d+)$");
        // You can now access the Index, X and Y by using the following statement
        // match.Groups["Index"];
        // match.Groups["X"];
        // match.Groups["Y"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read it as a string and use .Split(' ') which splits the string into an array of the separate strings. You can cast those to integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parse string to int

```
var coords=File.ReadAllText(path)
               .Split(new char[]{'\r',\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(i=>
                            new
                            {
                                 X=int.Parse(i.Split(' ')[1]),
                                 Y=int.Parse(i.Split(' ')[2])
                            }
                      );
```

---

You can now iterate over coords

```
foreach(var coordinate in coords)
{
    coordinate.X;
    coordinate.Y;
}
```